# How can I intercept a browser-server communication to see exactly what is being sent?

Tags: firefox, browser, proxy, diagnostic

I am having a problem identifying a cookie required by a particular website. I need to whitelist this cookie to get access this site. The site interaction involves several redirects, so there is no simple way to tell what data is passing back and forth between the web browser and the website server.

How can I temporarily record all of the data being transmitted between my web browser and the website? I mostly use Firefox, but I am envisioning some external system, maybe a proxy of some kind, that can spy on the HTTP/S requests and cookies and tell me what are for particular URLs.

Comment: What exactly is a “brower server”?

Comment: Anything external seems overkill for what you're trying to achieve, and introduces a lot of extra work to peek into HTTPS. Do you know your browser's developer tools, like [Firefox' network monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor)?

Comment: You can use wireshark or Mitm attack

Comment: @Arjan As I said in my question the problem involves several different layered redirects. The network monitor in Firefox only works for a single web page or destination address. It does work across redirects with multiple layered addresses.

Comment: You can literally see all of this in easy to follow context in your browser’s F12 developer mode. The next best thing, but not necessary is Fiddler. Wire shark will do nothing for you here.

Comment: @TylerDurden - have a Google for SSLKEYLOGFILE and Wireshark.  Firefox can use that.

Comment: _"The network monitor in Firefox only works for a single web page or destination address."_ As long as what you're investigating is running in a single browser tab, then"Persist logs" in the Firefox Network tab has always worked for me. But +1 for @HelpingHand's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to record just the requests (and redirects), you could install a
  free web proxy (e.g. [Privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org)) and evaluate its log files
  (`/var/log/privoxy.log`).
- If you want to record data exchange, [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) combined with a
  solid knowledge of protocols is the way to go.
- If the connection is encrypted, a proxy like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com) might be
  used to intercept/debug the connection - in this case, you have to
  make your browser accept a special certificate though.

Comment: As I said in the question, the requests include connections using HTTPS. Most proxies, including Privoxy do not support HTTPS.

Comment: @TylerDurden thanks for your time... While Privoxy in fact it does not support filtering/rewriting the *content* (which is its main area of application), it still **will** exhibit the requests (and redirects) just as stated, unless certain particular ancillary conditions are given (i.e. connection reuse).